# Convolutional neural network(CNN) python

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I have a question when working with CNN, please help, this is very important to me. Question in the comments under the video: https://youtu.be/N4Bk2N95CKQ

The question itself: 30: 06 why does convolution reduces the image by 2 pixels?

I, ask here,to avoid write here a bunch of layers of the neural network. 30:06 this is the time when the model.summary() has appeared on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in some cases convolution layer either uses padding or pixel removal in order to apply the given stride. So think of it like this. Your every step is worth two units and there is a bridge you must cross but you can only step on every odd number. Naturally you would try to shorten the bridge or start from one step behind.

If you need a rather more mathematical explanation. [Here](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/) is a good source about this whole convolution process.